# Sql error Error: ambiguous column name

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

I have a query:

```
select count(distinct RID) 
from MASTER_MOVIEVOD as M 
inner join RID_GENRE_MOVIEVOD as RG 
inner join GENRE_MOVIEVOD as G on M.RID=RG.RID and RG.GENRE_SR_NO=G.GENRE_SR_NO 
where M.UPDATE_PRESENT=1  
  and M.CLIP_TYPE=220 
  and M.PCAT=2 
  and G.GENRE_NAME!='Drama';
```

It gives me error

> Error: ambiguous column name: RID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because SQL doesn't know which `RID` to select `M.RID` or `RG.RID`, the ambiguity comes from here.

You have to choose one of them instead of `RID`:

```
select count(RG.RID) 
from MASTER_MOVIEVOD as M
..
```

Answer (score 1):

Add table identifier to `count`, because 2 of your tables has column `RID` you have to specify which one you want to use in your query

```
select count(distinct M.RID) 
from MASTER_MOVIEVOD as M 
inner join RID_GENRE_MOVIEVOD as RG 
inner join GENRE_MOVIEVOD as G on M.RID=RG.RID and RG.GENRE_SR_NO=G.GENRE_SR_NO 
where M.UPDATE_PRESENT=1 and M.CLIP_TYPE=220 and M.PCAT=2 and G.GENRE_NAME!='Drama';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the `RID`, write `COUNT(M.RID)` for example